# Spark Sql OR command not returning results

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run the following command in Zeppelin:

```
SELECT duration FROM voip where duration = 17 or  duration = 1
```

This doesn't return any results but while running them on there own the query returns results. I'm trying to run similar code in Scala as well but it doesn't work.

```
df.where(df("duration").===(1) || df("duration").===(2)).limit(10)
```

I can write something which just does each query and union all the data frames but I'm worried about performance. Any ideas?

Comment: It's unclear whether the scala version works or not? If it works, it looks like you are comparing strings in scala but ints in SQL. What is the schema?

Comment: Sorry can't post the schema, I had to change the the values I was searching to post. Niether work and ignore the quets around the Scala version they shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with isin function:

**df.where(df("duration").isin("1","2")).limit(10)**

```
 val df = Seq(30,1,2,3,4,5,6).toDF("duration")


 val df1 = df.where(df("duration").isin("1","2"))
 df1.show()


-----------------+
|duration         |
+-----------------+
|                1|
|                2|
+-----------------+
```